# GoogleSheets - Slicer on Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, slicers

I've created a pivot table and added a slicer which works fine

[image]

However I want to use the slicer on a different sheet (dashboard control)

But when I place the slicer on a different sheet (I tried copying the original slicer as well as creating it from scratch and specifying the reference data)

[image]

I am able to create the slicer, and it even gives me the option of selecting the column. But this slicer in the new sheet doesn't do anything. I pick Test 2 or Test 1 for the site and the pivot table doesn't filter

(I removed the original slicer first, so this new one on the new sheet is the only one)

Can slicers not be used on a different sheet to the data?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EIhWeAHZg5XhMvw8eCIeJdgaLd7kc6HzbIyGlI2HEmA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I created one that is more or less the same.
has 3 sheets, one with data, one with pivot table, and one where I want the slicer to go
but the slicer doesn't affect the pivot table when it is in another sheet

Comment: If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing and looking for documentations, I am not able to confirm that it works on other sheets. Based on my testing. It doesn't affect other sheets, just where the reference is and the slicer and pivot should be in the same sheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was trying to add a slicer to a graph that is based on a pivot table. The graph is in a separate sheet (along with other graphs as part of a dashboard), and the pivot table is used to aggregate raw data (also in its own sheet) for visualization purposes only and not particularly useful for user consumption. I then added a slicer that referenced the raw source data onto my dashboard sheet. Similar to OP, I couldn't get the slicer to work as intended with this setup. This issue seems to persist for graphs as well with no apparent solution for this use case.

I *did* find, however, that you can have a slicer on the **pivot table** and it be in the dashboard control and still work. I realize (as also in my case) that it doesn't solve your issue, but at least it might provide an alternative path to solving your problem if you can work your data in a different way.

Here's a copy of the sheet you provided to demonstrate the same issue for graphs as well along with a comparison to a slicer directed on the pivot table (please excuse the ugly graphs): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wX9crIPxs7mMTsBRMU84xfGoi4pF9rEiv-l2fYHfbak/edit?usp=sharing

It seems that Google Sheets currently only supports slicers that are "one degree" away or one degree of depth, **meaning you can not have any sheets in between the data source you want to filter and your desired output sheet**.